# Git pull request: dev into master without a new commit

Tags: git

Suppose this standard scenario:

- Two branches, dev and master, refs to the same commit C1.
- I commit something into dev, say C2, C3, C4.
- I want to merge dev into master. So I open a pull request (in GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, whatever) to merge dev into master (no squash, no delete source branch).
- I apply the pull request, and I see that a new commit C5 is being created: master refs to C5 and dev refs to C4.

Why? I want to maintain all dev history (so no squash, C2 C3 and C4) but when I merge into master I'd expect that dev and master ref both to C4. I don't see the need to create a new commit (and what should be the code differences between C4 and C5? They are identical), and I don't like that dev branch seems to be behind master while they contain the same code.

Can you explain to me why is that and if there is a better practice?

Comment: Taking Github for example, the document says "Pull requests are merged using the --no-ff option, except for pull requests with squashed or rebased commits, which are merged using the fast-forward option." With `--no-ff` it always creates a merge commit. See https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a `dev` branch from `master` branch at commit C1 and add commits C2, C3, C4 on the `dev` branch, the commit trees of both `master` and `dev` have diverged. Incorporating (specifically, "merge" and not "rebase") the changes from `dev` branch to `master` can be done in two ways -

1. Merging `dev` into `master` **without** fast-forwarding - The scenario you are facing falls under this category. What happens in non-Fast-forwarding scenarios is that your `dev` branch "*retains its identity*" despite being merged into `master`. The implication of this is that when you decide you do not want the changes brought in by the `dev` branch to `master` at a later point of time, you can easily revert the changes (multiple commits) brought in by the `dev` branch with a single revert in `master` on merge commit C5. The `dev` branch retains its "*identity*" through the merge-commit C5 created at the time of merge. This method is typically favoured & frequently employed in merging pull requests. However, it comes with the additional overhead of 1 merge commit for every merge. Merge with no fast-forwarding  can be done on the command-line with the following command on the `master` branch-

   ```
    git merge --no-ff dev
   ```

   Note the --no-ff flag indicating "no fast-forwarding"

Diagrammatic Illustration of commit tree of`master` after the merge -

```
       (dev)C2-C3-C4
           /        \
  (master)C1----------C5
```

2. Merging `dev` into `master` **with** fast-forwarding - This is the scenario you are expecting would happen upon merging `dev` into `master` via the pull request. In the case of fast-forwarding, the "identity" of the `dev` branch is lost as illustrated below. 
   Diagrammatic Illustration of commit tree of `master` after merge -

   ```
   (master) C1-C2-C3-C4
   ```

   In the figure for this case, at a later point in time (after more commits have been added to `master`), if you decide to delete the changes brought in by `dev` branch, you will not be able to exactly pinpoint at the commits which correspond to the `dev` branch (especially if the `dev` branch has been deleted). Thus, this is not the preferred method for merging pull requests where operations such as reverting are important. However, it is useful in scenarios where you are really sure the branch you are working on need not retain its identity. Fast-forwarding is also used in scenarios when you want to update your local copy of a branch with the branch it is tracking in the remote using `git pull`. The `git merge` command also resorts to fast-forwarding as its default behaviour.

**Note -** 
Please note that fast-forwarding is only applicable for merging branch `Y` into branch `X` if

1. No commits have been added to branch `X` after `Y` was split from it and,
2. New commits have been added to `Y` after it's split from `X`.

If both `X` and `Y` have new commits after split, then a fast-forward is not possible.

Reference - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html